# Android Logcat says "Unable to start activity Componentinfo

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, embed

I have been trying to embed my unity project into somebody's android project. and Here is problem I encountered and What I did to solve my problem. I cleaned project and rebuilt it but these didn't work. when I built my project in android studio, android studio printed this

Note: C:\Users\sense\NewGradPro_1211\UnityGame\androidBuild\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

This is also problem that my Logcat said

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77ERA.png)

and this is my MainUnityActivity java code in android studio

```
package com.hello.ourApplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class MainUnityActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup activity layout
        SharedClass.addControlsToUnityFrame(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        handleIntent(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null || intent.getExtras() == null) return;

        if (intent.getExtras().containsKey("doQuit")) {
            if (mUnityPlayer != null) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnityPlayerUnloaded() {
        SharedClass.showMainActivity("");
    }

}
```

I'm trying to embed my unity in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to do something simlar to "*Context.getString(*zero_value_variable*)*" by passing a value of Zero and it's "illegal".